# Help with a second menu - Admin Page

Tags: design, sidemenu

I'm doing  this second menu for a web site, but they told me is too much " old style" and they don't like the disposition of icon...
Any suggest for me please? Thank you

- The second menu is only in that section " flow designer/builder "
- in the grid it will be possible to draw flows, so I need the space of the menu to make visible, after the user choses icon, other configuration options as text input etc
- No much colors available...(I 'have already use them)

THANKS!!
[image]

Answer (score 0):

See some references and my opinion about each one:

1. Gutenberg blocks on Wordpress is a nice reference.
   [image]
2. This is interesting but the icons are terrible.
   [image]
3. It's quite more modern option.
   [image]
4. I particularly prefer this because don't have text, just icons. And looks clean.
   [image]
5. This I only added as an alternative for the way that you show the icons and texts.
   [image]

Of course, you can get the best idea of each one and create your own design. The sizes, fonts, icons, colours and spaces will make the difference. I hope that these alternative ideas (not design reference) could help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think making use of space and ordering information is the best way to go about this feature.

You could align the icons in a one single line rather than 3 columns. Thus making better use of the space, that is, more visible space for the grid. (see below)

[image]

You can also group the 3 sections first and have a third menu showing up with all the correspondent icons. Thus improving information architecture, grouping things and showing only relevant information, and also making good use of space (see below)

[image]
[image]

Hope this helps.
Cheers!