# How to display multi level multiple tab or options in UI?

Tags: usability, tabs

For my project, i am having the following need.

1. We have folder tree kind of options in Left side ( say it as folder )
2. Each folder has its own multiple options ( say it as 'opt1,2 etc' )
3. Each opt1,2, etc has some details as list view ( say it as 'Listing' )
4. On clicking the Listing, it has other set of options related to that.

At best, i was tried to showcase it as prototype and it looks like below image. I feel something bit odd on showing second level of options ( second level tabs ) so please help me any better way to capture multi level multiple tab use case.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use as an alternative the material Design tabs as a reference. You can hide some unused or fewer important menus but if user swipe, then he can see it.

See image example and see more in https://material.io/design/components/tabs.html#usage
[image]

And on this post, you can see some alternatives that I suggested for other similar situation.
[Help with a second menu - Admin Page](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/125336/help-with-a-second-menu-admin-page/125350#125350)

Answer (score 0):

Material Design also do not recommend using nested tabs:
https://m2.material.io/components/tabs#placement
they say in a very strict way: "Caution. Avoid nesting a tab within another tab."

We can look here: https://m3.material.io/components/tabs/guidelines
this site uses a well-designed multi-level side menu, while each page has ±4 tabs for different sections. IMHO: Multi-level side menu solves the issue: [image: multilevel menu example]

Comment: "*Caution. Avoid nesting a tab within another tab*" — Yet nested tabs can sometimes be very handy. For my own reference I recorded [all the changes I made when installing Ubuntu)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bs5f.png) on my home system. This has tabs going four levels deep, and has proved to be very useful and easy to navigate.